# What are my options to build and test a Phonegap app in Windows

Tags: cordova

I have zero experience with Phonegap but I have a phonegap app with 3 directories, one for each of the Android, Blackberry, and IPhone platforms.

What are my options to build and test this on a Windows machine? I tried opening the Index.html file but it just runs the static html and not the app code.

I am enthusiastic to dive in and play with the code but I am just clueless on how to run it.

Thanks.

Comment: I develop just fine on Windows (everything except iOS which you need a mac for.) You can use either an emulator or an actual device (I use Android devices and a Blackberry emulator.) Check out the various guides here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Cordova command-line interface yet?  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: An emulator sounds like a nice solution. Is there any way to test the IOS directory in Windows? Does it really require a Mac?

Comment: checkout build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

You can build and run apps for Android, WP, BlackBerry with the related SDKs : 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides

You can for each of them use an emulator or a real device if you install drivers for it.

In order to develop for iOS on windows, you can create a OS X virtual machine and use it to build/run your project on iOS platform.

In order to do that I follow this tuto in French : http://www.tech2tech.fr/comment-installer-os-x-mountain-lion-sur-virtualbox-avec-iatkos/

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of the phonegap and extract, you would find the folder for window under the lib folder .so Please navigate inside the folder and open the solution file with visual studio, before all this u need to install windows mobile in system .